# Why use EnumFieldType in Solr?

Tags: solr

While looking for potential ways to decrease the size of our Solr indices I found the [EnumFieldType](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/enum-fields.html).

Since our documents all share a field `objectType` with a defined and rather constant list of possible values, I thought it might be a good option to use the `EnumFieldType` for this field.

But after recreating the index (with about 150k docs) I have not been able to measure any improvement in terms of index size.

Can anyone tell me more about the benefits I could expect when using the `EnumFieldType`? The documentation does not  tell much about that (besides the ability to explicitly define the order of the values this way), and during a short research in the web I couldn't find much, neither.

Comment: One benefit is likely to enforce only valid values are stored/indexed. If you try to insert a document with a value out of range of the enul, it would fail.

Comment: Yeah, that's true - though I wonder if that kind of value validation is not a little late in the data acquisition and maintenance process ;-)